# How to create a working Skinned Mesh Renderer manually?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

When manually creating a Game Object and adding a Skinned Mesh Renderer component, it doesn't show anything when it should show my model, even though the model is selected in the settings. When dragging in an fbx asset with animations into the scene, it automatically creates the necessary Skinned Mesh Renderer component, and this one shows the model. Even though my manual settings are identical to the one generated by Unity, it still doesn't show the model unless I copy the settings from the working component to the nonworking one. What is going on here? Is there some settings I cannot see that are getting copied?

Edit: additional info

Unity version 2020.3.17f1

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create Game Object
   [image: Step 1]
2. Create Skinned Mesh Renderer component
   [image: Step 2]
3. I set mesh and root bone here, as well as materials
   [image: Step 3]
4. Mesh does not show in game or in scene view
   [image: Step 4]
5. Drag asset into the scene to create a Game Object
   [image: Step 5]
6. This shows correctly when done this way
   [image: Step 6]
7. Copy settings
   [image: Step 7]
8. Paste settings
   [image: Step 8]
9. Delete the unwanted object
   [image: Step 9]
10. The Original object is now showing
    [image: Step 10]

Comment: Which settings are you copying to make it work? I guess the main thing would be the `mesh`, `bones` and `material(s)` ... And could you show us your code?

Comment: @derHugo I added more information

Comment: One thing I can see is that the materials are in wrong order on the manual created one and there are no bounds which sounds a bit like your Skinned mesh renderer somehow wasn't refreshed correctly after the mesh was assigned

Comment: The thing about the materials is true, but I have tried making them exact too, it doesn't work either way. Once I get a model showing by copy and pasting the settings, it allows me to switch the model just fine, but the bounds don't automatically switch. I have tried manually adding bounds and that doesn't work either. Is there some C# code to refresh the bounds or the whole model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used C# to copy various properties from the working one to the nonworking one until one appeared to make it show, bones. There is no bones tab in the inspector for Skinned Mesh Renderer as it appears to be hidden from view.

To repeat more simply, setting SkinnedMeshRenderer.bones in C# is what made the model show.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of copying/editing/pasting one skinned mesh renderer's bones to another.

**SkinnedmeshBonesTransfer.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class SkinnedmeshBonesTransfer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SkinnedMeshRenderer sourceMeshRenderer;
    public SkinnedMeshRenderer targetMeshRenderer;
    public Transform[] bones;

    public bool getBones;
    public bool setBones;

    private void Update()
    {
        if(getBones)
        {
            getBones = false;

            bones = sourceMeshRenderer.bones;
        }
        if (setBones)
        {
            setBones = false;

            targetMeshRenderer.bones = bones;
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. I don't get this dumb limitation of not being allowed to comment on another answer, so instead, I had to write a separate answer.

Comment: How do I use this script exactly? thanks.

Comment: Just create a C# script named SkinnedmeshBonesTransfer.cs, paste this code in it, and save, then drag and drop it onto a GameObject in the scene, fill the variables in the inspector, and click on wanted checkmarks to execute that code. I know it's best to create an editor tool and run it via an editor window but that would kill the simplicity and overcomplicate things.